# Array Methods to Match Values in Two Arrays and Return a Filtered Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to determine what combination of .filter or .some I need to get the data I need in my MongoDB collection.

First off, I have a docs array, that looks like this:

```
let docs = [
 { _id: '5ba39a12179b771820413ad8',
  branches:
   [ { _id: '3nc26645121f0613be08167r', name: 'New York' },
     { _id: '3fc26645121f0613be08185d', name: 'Los Angeles' },
     { _id: '2hc26648121f0613be081862', name: 'Seattle' },
     { _id: '7jc2664a121f0613be081869', name: 'Chicago' },
     { _id: '7ju2664a121f0613be08186e', name: 'Charlotte' } ],
  updatedAt: '2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z',
  createdAt: '2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z' },
{ _id: '3ya39a12179b771820413af5',
  branches:
   [ { _id: '3nc26645121f0613be08167r', name: 'New York' },
     { _id: '5ac26645121f0613be08145d', name: 'Miami' },
     { _id: '5ac2664a121f0613be08154s', name: 'Sacramento' } ],
  updatedAt: '2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z',
  createdAt: '2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z' 
 },
{ _id: '2sa39a12179b771820413gy4',
  branches:
   [ { _id: '1rd26645121d5613be08167h', name: 'Denver' },
     { _id: '5ac2664a121f0613be08154s', name: 'Sacramento' } ],
  updatedAt: '2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z',
  createdAt: '2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z' 
 }
];
```

And I have an array of passed-in user values, which are IDs, that looks like this:

```
 let filterValues = ["5ac26645121f0613be08145d", "7ju2664a121f0613be08186e"];
```

Now what I want to write is a query that will return a new `docs` array that just contains the docs that had a match between the IDs in the `filterValues` array and the IDs found within the `branches` property (which is an array) on the root of each document.

In the example I've provided here, the resulting array should contain 2 of the 3 docs from the original `docs` array - the first two, to be specific, because they both contain at least one of the IDs passed in within their respective `branches` array - the IDs assigned to Charlotte and Miami from my docs data.

Is there a way I can write this using `.filter`, `.includes`, or perhaps `.some`, or some combination?

To be clear, the final filtered result should look like this:

```
 [
     { _id: '5ba39a12179b771820413ad8',
      branches:
       [ { _id: '3nc26645121f0613be08167r', name: 'New York' },
         { _id: '3fc26645121f0613be08185d', name: 'Los Angeles' },
         { _id: '2hc26648121f0613be081862', name: 'Seattle' },
         { _id: '7jc2664a121f0613be081869', name: 'Chicago' },
         { _id: '7ju2664a121f0613be08186e', name: 'Charlotte' } ],
      updatedAt: '2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z',
      createdAt: '2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z' },
    { _id: '3ya39a12179b771820413af5',
      branches:
       [ { _id: '3nc26645121f0613be08167r', name: 'New York' },
         { _id: '5ac26645121f0613be08145d', name: 'Miami' },
         { _id: '5ac2664a121f0613be08154s', name: 'Sacramento' } ],
      updatedAt: '2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z',
      createdAt: '2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z' 
     }
 ];
```

Comment: there are tow id's which one you want to match one outside branches or inside ?

Comment: I want to return the docs where that doc's branches property had an _id that matches one of the passed in filter values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange that you haven't implemented this yourself given that you already proposed tools that should be used... well, almost.

First, you need to get a subset of `docs` based on a condition, and `.filter` what is designed for this, so

```
var filteredDocs = docs.filter(doc =>
    // here we need an expression of whether the doc.branches contains an id from filterValues
)
```

Next, you have to find if any of the `.branches` of a `doc` have an id from `filterValues`, `.branches` is an array, so `.some` is suitable here:

```
var filteredDocs = docs.filter(doc =>
    doc.branches.some(branch =>
        // here an expression should check whether branch._id is among filterValues
    )
)
```

Finally, you need to check whether `branch._id` is among `filterValues`, the simplest way to do that is to use `.includes` (you can use `.some` as well, but there's no point to do so since ids are.. unique):

```
var filteredDocs = docs.filter(doc =>
    doc.branches.some(branch =>
        filterValues.includes(branch._id)
    )
)
```

You can use it as a one-liner which is a bit more difficult to read:

```
var filteredDocs = docs.filter(doc => doc.branches.some(branch => filterValues.includes(branch._id)))
```

Trying this in console will show you the result (note that in your post syntax for `docs` is incorrect):

```
var docs = [
 { _id: '5ba39a12179b771820413ad8',
  branches:
   [ { _id: '3nc26645121f0613be08167r', name: 'New York' },
     { _id: '3fc26645121f0613be08185d', name: 'Los Angeles' },
     { _id: '2hc26648121f0613be081862', name: 'Seattle' },
     { _id: '7jc2664a121f0613be081869', name: 'Chicago' },
     { _id: '7ju2664a121f0613be08186e', name: 'Charlotte' } ],
  updatedAt: '2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z',
  createdAt: '2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z' },
{ _id: '3ya39a12179b771820413af5',
  branches:
   [ { _id: '3nc26645121f0613be08167r', name: 'New York' },
     { _id: '5ac26645121f0613be08145d', name: 'Miami' },
     { _id: '5ac2664a121f0613be08154s', name: 'Sacramento' } ],
  updatedAt: '2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z',
  createdAt: '2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z' 
 },
{ _id: '2sa39a12179b771820413gy4',
  branches:
   [ { _id: '1rd26645121d5613be08167h', name: 'Denver' },
     { _id: '5ac2664a121f0613be08154s', name: 'Sacramento' } ],
  updatedAt: '2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z',
  createdAt: '2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z' 
 }
];

let filterValues = ["5ac26645121f0613be08145d", "7ju2664a121f0613be08186e"];

var filteredDocs = docs.filter(doc =>
    doc.branches.some(branch =>
        filterValues.includes(branch._id)
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, will this give me `docs` as an array containing two objects like I have in my question above (see the code I added)? When I tried it I get an empty array?

Comment: @Muirik why not try it yourself in console? I've even prepared it for copy-pasting :) `docs` will stay the same and `filteredDocs` will contain only 2 objects. If you need to change `docs`, just overwrite them like `docs = docs.filter(.....`

Comment: This looks to be working. And I like how succinct it is. Many thanks, @YakovL.

Comment: @Muirik you are welcome. But honestly, once you prepared your question that well, I suggest you to try to crack it yourself. That's how I usually don't ask at SO :) Preparing a clear question usually suggests adequate ways to solve it

Comment: I knew it would likely be a combination of `.filter`, `.some`, and `.includes`, but I wasn't able to get the syntax right. Sometimes, after you've been drumming your head against the wall for a couple of hours, you're better off just getting a second set of eyes to give it a go.

Comment: @Muirik fair enough

Answer (score 3):

```
 const result =  array.filter(({ branches }) => branches.some(({ _id }) => filterValues.includes(_id)))
```

How about if you just do what you think you want to do.

Comment: Could you please add a small explanation, because it may be not really clear to everyone?

Comment: Yes, please provide a little more detail. So in my case, it would be docs.filter, right? And what does "branches.some" represent in the above code? The branches on the root of each doc document?

Comment: When I try:     `const finalDocs = docs.filter(({ branches }) => branches.some(({ _id }) => arrBranchID.includes(_id)));` -- and then `console.log(finalDocs)` I get an empty array as the result.

Comment: Very difficult to follow this kind of coding syntax from Jonas Wilms or maybe I am slow-minded folk

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of what you are trying to do:

```js
const data = [{ _id: "5ba39a12179b771820413ad8", branches: [{ _id: "3nc26645121f0613be08167r", name: 'New York' }, { _id: "3fc26645121f0613be08185d", name: 'Los Angeles' }, { _id: "2hc26648121f0613be081862", name: 'Seattle' }, { _id: "7jc2664a121f0613be081869", name: 'Chicago' }, { _id: "7ju2664a121f0613be08186e", name: 'Charlotte' } ], updatedAt: "2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z", createdAt: "2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z" }, { _id: "3ya39a12179b771820413af5", branches: [{ _id: "3nc26645121f0613be08167r", name: 'New York' }, { _id: "5ac26645121f0613be08145d", name: 'Miami' }, { _id: "5ac2664a121f0613be08154s", name: 'Sacramento' } ], updatedAt: "2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z", createdAt: "2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z " }, { _id: "2sa39a12179b771820413gy4", branches: [{ _id: "1rd26645121d5613be08167h", name: 'Denver' }, { _id: "5ac2664a121f0613be08154s", name: 'Sacramento' } ], updatedAt: "2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z", createdAt: "2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z " } ]
const vals = ["5ac26645121f0613be08145d", "7ju2664a121f0613be08186e"]

const result = data.filter(x => x.branches.some(y => vals.includes(y._id)))

console.log(result)
```

This is the short ES6 version which uses arrow functions etc for conciseness mainly here. Expanded this would be:

```js
const data = [{ _id: "5ba39a12179b771820413ad8", branches: [{ _id: "3nc26645121f0613be08167r", name: 'New York' }, { _id: "3fc26645121f0613be08185d", name: 'Los Angeles' }, { _id: "2hc26648121f0613be081862", name: 'Seattle' }, { _id: "7jc2664a121f0613be081869", name: 'Chicago' }, { _id: "7ju2664a121f0613be08186e", name: 'Charlotte' } ], updatedAt: "2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z", createdAt: "2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z" }, { _id: "3ya39a12179b771820413af5", branches: [{ _id: "3nc26645121f0613be08167r", name: 'New York' }, { _id: "5ac26645121f0613be08145d", name: 'Miami' }, { _id: "5ac2664a121f0613be08154s", name: 'Sacramento' } ], updatedAt: "2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z", createdAt: "2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z " }, { _id: "2sa39a12179b771820413gy4", branches: [{ _id: "1rd26645121d5613be08167h", name: 'Denver' }, { _id: "5ac2664a121f0613be08154s", name: 'Sacramento' } ], updatedAt: "2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z", createdAt: "2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z " } ]
const vals = ["5ac26645121f0613be08145d", "7ju2664a121f0613be08186e"]

const result = data.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj.branches.some(function(branch) {
    return vals.includes(branch._id)
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

Basically you first would like to `filter` the main array (via [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) and inside you are using [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which would check if any of the `branches` _ids are included (via [`Array.include`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)) in the `filter` array. Simple as that.

Comment: I added what the result should look like to my question. Basically it should be an array with two elements. See above.

Comment: How is it different than the result from this answer? You are getting an array with the 2 objects in which branches the _ids ware found.

Comment: Sorry, I misread what you had. You're right. This should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```js
let docs = [{ _id: "5ba39a12179b771820413ad8", branches: [{ _id: "3nc26645121f0613be08167r", name: 'New York' }, { _id: "3fc26645121f0613be08185d", name: 'Los Angeles' }, { _id: "2hc26648121f0613be081862", name: 'Seattle' }, { _id: "7jc2664a121f0613be081869", name: 'Chicago' }, { _id: "7ju2664a121f0613be08186e", name: 'Charlotte' } ], updatedAt: "2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z", createdAt: "2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z" }, { _id: "3ya39a12179b771820413af5", branches: [{ _id: "3nc26645121f0613be08167r", name: 'New York' }, { _id: "5ac26645121f0613be08145d", name: 'Miami' }, { _id: "5ac2664a121f0613be08154s", name: 'Sacramento' } ], updatedAt: "2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z", createdAt: "2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z " }, { _id: "2sa39a12179b771820413gy4", branches: [{ _id: "1rd26645121d5613be08167h", name: 'Denver' }, { _id: "5ac2664a121f0613be08154s", name: 'Sacramento' } ], updatedAt: "2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z", createdAt: "2018-09-20T13:01:06.709Z " } ]
let filterValues = ["5ac26645121f0613be08145d", "7ju2664a121f0613be08186e"]

let result = [];
// For every items in docs
_.each(docs, item => {
  // Filter an item with filter values
  filterValues.forEach (value => {
    if (_.findWhere(item.branches, {_id: value})) {
      // Check and store it in the array
      result.push(item);
    }
  });
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://fastcdn.org/Underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```